# Sequence search method for obtaining the state of an object at runtime

Tags: java

I'm solving the following problem:

I have a Java object. It is necessary to obtain any sequence of methods, starting with construction, that were applied to this object, as a result of which it appeared.

Are there any libraries or ways that do this?

I'm currently using reflection. I'm trying to apply all the methods to an object to get the required